# Volta and global npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, volta

I try Volta tools on existing Node project. This is very great tools :)

But, can i use global package ? For example, i've run :

`npm i -g gitmoji-cli`

Then, i try to use `gitmoji`, but it's undefined on the command line. I'm on the right node version, but i don't really understand why the gitmoji is not found.

Do you know if I need other param ?

If anyone have already use this tool and installing global package .. :)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can install global packages using `volta install <package>`. In your case, it would be `volta install gitmoji-cli`.

Volta will then install the package and make it available anywhere in your terminal. However, if you open the terminal in a project that has that package listed as a dependency, or dev dependency, Volta will use the package from the `node_modules` of that project instead.

For more information see: [global-installs-done-right](https://blog.volta.sh/2019/06/18/global-installs-done-right/)

Comment: Is there a way to refer the globally installed package in a local script?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Volta works Well with global package installation.

I try your command and it's OK:

```
npm i -g gitmoji-cli
```

if it's not working for you, try openning "cmd" with "Run as administrator" option.

or, as [volta documentation](https://docs.volta.sh/guide/getting-started) recommends, enable "Developer Mode" in Windows:

> NOTE
>
> Volta's functionality depends on creating symlinks, so you must
> either:
>
> Enable [Developer Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development#accessing-settings-for-developers) (recommended)
>
> Run Volta with elevated privileges (not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

When you install a package to your toolchain, Volta takes your current default Node version and pins the tool to that engine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).