# ''pm2' is not recognized as an internal command with volta install

Tags: node.js, pm2, volta

I install volta as node version handler and when I run pm2 status/start/stop in PowerShell or cmd, there is
*'pm2' is not recognized as an internal command' error.*

I know that I should install pm2 as global but run `npm i -g pm2` it is not working and have same error. Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

by this [answer of Volta and global npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66312977/6777872) I just run `volta install pm2` instead of `npm i -g pm2` and set Volta/bin in environment variable of windows. in [Global installs done right](https://blog.volta.sh/2019/06/18/global-installs-done-right/) said:

> By running volta install mocha, you let Volta know that you want mocha to be available everywhere in your terminal